# Convert bitmap to Base64 using Base64InputStream

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, android-bitmap

I'm working on an Android app that will send a Base64 encoded image to a backend. Since some images are large (and I've been getting Out of Memory errors because of this) I want to use the `Base64InputStream` to encode the images.

I currently have the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Base64InputStream;
```

...

```
public static String convertBitmapToBase64String(Context context, Bitmap bmp)
{

    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
        byte[] bmpInByteArray = fos.toByteArray();

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bmpInByteArray);
        final InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(in, Base64.DEFAULT);

        //Now that we have the InputStream, we can read it and put it into the String
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(base64InputStream, writer, "UTF-8");

        String res = writer.toString();

        DataUtils.log("Base64 is: " + res);
        return res;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        DataUtils.log(e.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}
```

However this isn't working. I'm always getting an exception on the `IOUtils.copy(base64InputStream, writer, "UTF-8");` line with a message saying "bad base-64".

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You must use Base64OutputStream, instead of Base64InputStream.

```
// Convert bitmap to base-64 png
ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream base64FilterStream = new Base64OutputStream(byteStream, 0);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, base64FilterStream);

base64FilterStream.flush();
byteStream.flush();
base64FilterStream.close();
byteStream.close();

String base64String = byteStream.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

final InputStream base64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(in, Base64.DEFAULT);

i think you should use  `final InputStream base64InputStream= = new Base64InputStream(in, Base64.DEFAULT,true);`   instead;

because you are doing encode job.

```
public Base64InputStream(InputStream in, int flags) {
    this(in, flags, false);
}
/**
 * Performs Base64 encoding or decoding on the data read from the
 * wrapped InputStream.
 *
 * @param in the InputStream to read the source data from
 * @param flags bit flags for controlling the decoder; see the
 *        constants in {@link Base64}
 * @param encode true to encode, false to decode
 *
 * @hide
 */
public Base64InputStream(InputStream in, int flags, boolean encode)
```

Comment: The `Base64InputStream` class I'm using is from `android.util.Base64InputStream`, which does not have this constructor. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64InputStream.html

Comment: the code below my help 
` ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Base64OutputStream outputStream=new Base64OutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, Base64.DEFAULT);
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bmpInByteArray);
            IoUtils.copyStream(in,outputStream,null); 
            try {
                String res=new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`

Comment: When using this Eclipse gives me the following error: `The method copyStream(InputStream, Base64OutputStream, null) is undefined for the type IOUtils`

Comment: you can do it yourself,ignore the IoUtils Method,just java IO operation.

Comment: It seems to return a valid base64 string when the image is small, but I still get a Out of Memory error when a large image is used.

Comment: Big image always has such problem , so write   to a file,and handle that file.  use fileOuputStream instead ByteArrayOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to convert bitmap to base64 string

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
 byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: The `Base64.encodeToString` part is what fails for large bitmaps. This is the reason I'm trying to use Base64InputStream instead.